# How can I execute a python script on a given region of my buffer?

Tags: python, region

I have a `.tex` source and a `python` script called `comments.py`. This script reads my `.tex` source as input, does some operations on it and write a `.com` file as output. Then I have to reneame `.com` as `.tex` and go on with my work.

I want to automate these procedure and so I have written a script in `elisp` to do this.

**My problem**

I want that `comments.py` acts on a given region of my `.tex` source and not on all buffer. So, how can I contain its actions from `(point-min)` to a point defined as `\begin{thebibliography}`?

Here there is my code:

```
;; clean comments on .tex sources

;; define .tex file name with extension
(setq source-tex-ext (format "%s" (buffer-name)))

;; call comments.py
(defun call-comments ()
  (interactive)
  (setq python-script-path "~/scripts/comments.py")
  (insert
   (shell-command-to-string
    (concat
     (format "python %s" python-script-path) (format " %s" buffer-file-name)))))

(call-comments)

(save-buffer)

;; close buffer
(kill-buffer (current-buffer))

;;
;;
;; Now I call a bash script in order to rename .tex as .bkp and then .com as .tex 
;; because I am not able to do this in elisp directly
;;
;;

;; call rename-com-to-tex.sh
(defun call-bash-script ()
 (interactive)
 (setq bash-script-path "~/myscripts/rename-com-to-tex.sh")
 (call-process "/bin/bash" nil t nil bash-script-path))

(call-bash-script)

;; open .tex (this is .com renamed as .tex)
(find-file (format "%s" source-tex-ext))

(save-buffer)


;; do other things
...
```

Hope my question is clear.

**Hint**

This is an attempt with `shell-command-on-region` as suggested (I have tried to construct the following code looking for examples):

```
(setq m1 (make-marker))
(goto-char (point-min))
(set-marker m1 (point-min))

(setq m2 (make-marker))
(set-marker m2 (search-forward "\\begin{thebibliography}"))
(setq python-script-path "~/scripts/comments.py")

;; call comments.py
(defun call-comments (start-position end-position)
  (interactive "r")
  (shell-command-on-region
   start-position end-position (concat
    (format "python %s" python-script-path) (format " %s" (buffer-file-name))) (buffer-file-name) nil))

 (call-comments m1 m2)
```

In this way the code creates a `.com` file as output, but restrictions are ignored. In the new `.com` file, `comments.py` has acted until the end and not until `\begin{thebibliography}`.

Comment: What about `shell-command-on-region`?

Comment: Can `comments.py` read from standard input instead of taking a filename?

Comment: @npostavs In the source of `comments.py` appears `open(...)`, then I think that it must have a file as input, but I am not a `python` programmer, so I do not asnwer about this. I can not publish `comments.py` for confidentiality obligations.

Comment: @OnnerIrotsab you can try using shell redirection `python comments.py < some-file` and see if it works.

Comment: @npostavs Sorry, I do not understand what  you mean...

Comment: I mean, open a shell, and run `python ~/scripts/comments.py < my-file.tex`, where `my-file.tex` is the path to your tex file. If the `comments.py` prints some kind of error in reponse, then you know it can't use standard input.

Comment: @npostavs Thank you!  I have tried and yes, there are some errors.